# Market making future and underlying spot

Tags: futures, market-making

I am learning about market making and have been reading papers by Avellaneda-Stoikov, Bayraktar-Ludvkosli and L-Guéant-Fernandez. All of them attempt to maximize utility function but are based on a single order book. Are there any papers that propose a market making algorithm when two limit order books are perfectly correlated? Like a future and spot on the same underlying? I am sure there are models that can control inventory by skewing quotes and balancing inventory on both the order books?

Any reference paper please advise.